# Pandas: how can I generate "year-month" format column (period)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
In [20]: df.head()
Out[20]:
   year  month     capital       sales      income      profit         debt 
0  2000      6 -19250379.0  37924704.0  -4348337.0   2571738.0  192842551.0
1  2000     12 -68357153.0  27870187.0 -49074146.0 -20764204.0  190848380.0
2  2001      6 -65048960.0  30529435.0  -1172803.0   2000427.0  197383572.0
3  2001     12 -90129943.0  17135480.0 -24208501.0  -1012230.0  191464941.0
4  2002      6  14671980.0  31377347.0   2188125.0   3660938.0  101355088.0
```

What I tried was:

`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']*10000 + df['month']*100, format="%Y%m")`

but it occurred an error:

```
In [21]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']*10000 + df['month']*100, format="%Y%m"
    ...: )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-31bfca8c5941> in <module>()
----> 1 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']*10000 + df['month']*100, format="%Y%m")

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin)
    507     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
    508         from pandas import Series
--> 509         values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, False, format)
    510         result = Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    511     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, MutableMapping)):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
    412                     try:
    413                         result = tslib.array_strptime(arg, format, exact=exact,
--> 414                                                       errors=errors)
    415                     except tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime:
    416                         if errors == 'raise':

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_strptime (pandas/_libs/tslib.c:63753)()

TypeError: 'int' object is unsliceable
```

I think this is because 'day' is missed.

How can I do this?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.year.astype(str) + df.month.astype(str), format='%Y%m')`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
In [223]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month']].assign(day=1)).dt.to_period('M')

In [224]: df
Out[224]:
   year  month     capital       sales      income      profit         debt    date
0  2000      6 -19250379.0  37924704.0  -4348337.0   2571738.0  192842551.0 2000-06
1  2000     12 -68357153.0  27870187.0 -49074146.0 -20764204.0  190848380.0 2000-12
2  2001      6 -65048960.0  30529435.0  -1172803.0   2000427.0  197383572.0 2001-06
3  2001     12 -90129943.0  17135480.0 -24208501.0  -1012230.0  191464941.0 2001-12
4  2002      6  14671980.0  31377347.0   2188125.0   3660938.0  101355088.0 2002-06
```

or

```
In [208]: df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month']].assign(day=1)),
                                      freq='M')

In [209]: df
Out[209]:
   year  month     capital       sales      income      profit         debt    date
0  2000      6 -19250379.0  37924704.0  -4348337.0   2571738.0  192842551.0 2000-06
1  2000     12 -68357153.0  27870187.0 -49074146.0 -20764204.0  190848380.0 2000-12
2  2001      6 -65048960.0  30529435.0  -1172803.0   2000427.0  197383572.0 2001-06
3  2001     12 -90129943.0  17135480.0 -24208501.0  -1012230.0  191464941.0 2001-12
4  2002      6  14671980.0  31377347.0   2188125.0   3660938.0  101355088.0 2002-06
```

Comment: @user3595632 you may consider up-voting this answer in addition to accepting.

Comment: @piRSquared What's the difference?

Comment: [**This Link Should Help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) But in short, Accepting the answer declares one of the answers as the one that answered your question.  When more than one satisfies that requirement, you choose the best one, or the one you found most useful.  However, once you reach 15 reputation, you're given 40 votes a day.  I use mine to up-vote good answers because it serves the community to help identify good answers.  I also ask a lot of questions.  In that context I up-vote good answers to show my gratitude.  Up-votes are worth 10 rep to the one you up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass series to `PeriodIndex`, so this works:

```py
df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(
    year=df['year'],
    month=df['month'],
    freq='M',
)
```

If you specifically want a `Timestamp` instead of a `Period`, you can pass a `dict` to `to_datetime()` and set the day to `1`:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime({
    'year': df['year'],
    'month': df['month'],
    'day': 1,
})
```