# Time Series Plotting with Matplotlib only the value of the Month

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, time-series

I have a dataset which consists of 3 columns (`Month`, `Year`, `Individuals`).
What I am trying to do is to plot a linegraph showing me the value of `Individuals` for each `Month`:
2015-1 5000 2015-2 10000 2015-3 1200 and so on.

At the moment the graph looks like this:

```
df.to_dict
{'month': {Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 1,
  Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'): 2,
  Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00'): 3,
  Timestamp('2015-01-04 00:00:00'): 4,
  Timestamp('2015-01-05 00:00:00'): 5,
  Timestamp('2015-01-06 00:00:00'): 6,
  Timestamp('2015-01-07 00:00:00'): 7,
  Timestamp('2015-01-08 00:00:00'): 8,
  Timestamp('2015-01-09 00:00:00'): 9,
  Timestamp('2015-01-10 00:00:00'): 10,
  Timestamp('2015-01-11 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2015-01-12 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 1,
  Timestamp('2016-01-02 00:00:00'): 2,
  Timestamp('2016-01-03 00:00:00'): 3,
  Timestamp('2016-01-04 00:00:00'): 4,
  Timestamp('2016-01-05 00:00:00'): 5,
  Timestamp('2016-01-06 00:00:00'): 6,
  Timestamp('2016-01-07 00:00:00'): 7,
  Timestamp('2016-01-08 00:00:00'): 8,
  Timestamp('2016-01-09 00:00:00'): 9,
  Timestamp('2016-01-10 00:00:00'): 10,
```

[image: Current graph]

But I am trying to get Something like this:

[image: Desired graph]

I would appreciate any help.

Sample of Data:
[Sample of DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teyCs.png)

Data:

```
month year individuals
1     2015 5000
2     2015 7000
3     2015 10000
4       .
.       .
.       .
12      .  100000
1      2016 73000
```

New `Date` column:

[image: New Date Column]

Comment: Please share a sample of your data, otherwise it is very difficult to help

Comment: Hey, i just added a screenshot of the data

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot, please copy and paste your data into the question so that others can easily copy and paste it. A screenshot is rarely helpful.

Comment: i added some sample data hope that helps.

Comment: Make a new date column using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46310844/11946287) and then use that as your `x` variable

Comment: I already did that, it didnt change much. I used the year and the month to create the Date and used this as the index for the Dataframe:
'# Create Date Column with year and month 
`# Create Date Column with year and month 
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["year"].astype(str) + df["month"].astype(str) , format = '%Y%d')
# Date as Index
df = df.set_index("Date")`

Comment: But haven’t you formatted it as year and day instead of year and month? Just a reminder I said don’t post screenshots of your data, it would be far more useful to copy the output of `df.to_dict()` into your question

Comment: I just added that. Cant figure out why the data looks like this.

Comment: also tried the answer u suggested to me and it looks alot better now. Thank u alot.